# Expanding Option[_] over a Product in Shapeless

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I'm learning my way through Shapeless, and I have a specific behavior I'm looking to implement to allow our code to expand out optional case classes identically whether they're present or not. Basically:

Given an `Option[N]` where `N <: Product`, I'd like to produce an `HList` with the same types produced by `Generic[N].to`, but with each element wrapped in an `Option` if it isn't already. e.g.:

```scala
case class Foo(a: String, b: Option[Long], c: Option[String])

optionalize[Foo](Some(Foo("abc", Some(123L), None)))
// => Some("abc") :: Some(123L) :: None :: HNil

optionalize[Foo](None)
// => None :: None :: None :: HNil

// where optionalize.Out = Option[String] :: Option[Long] :: Option[String] :: HNil
```

My ultimate goal is the ability to flatten out nested case classes, so I'd like to introduce this as a rule such that Shapeless can do this automatically via type inference. The biggest obstacle in my mind is understanding how to write the `None` case. Currently, my code looks something like this:

```scala
trait LowPriEnsureOptional extends Poly1 {
  implicit def somethingCase[In]: Case.Aux[In, Option[In]] = at(thing => Some(thing))
  implicit val hnilCase: Case.Aux[HNil, HNil] = at(identity)
}

object EnsureOptional extends LowPriEnsureOptional {
  implicit def optionCase[In <: Option[_]]: Case.Aux[In, In] = at(identity)
}

object OptionizeHlist {

  def optionizeCaseClass[
    CC <: Product,
    R <: HList
  ](occ: Option[CC])(
    implicit gen: Generic[CC] { type Repr = R },
    optionalize: Mapper[EnsureOptional.type, R]
  ): optionalize.Out =
    occ match {
      case Some(cc) => optionalize.apply(gen.to(cc))
      case None     => ???
    }
}
```

To write out the `None` case, I need some way to, given a case class, get its generic repr, run it through `OptionizeHlist`, and generate an instance of it consisting entirely of `None`s, but I have no idea where to start on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, if you are passed a `None`, type erasure makes it so that you cannot know how many `None`s to put into the output list. Therefore, you need another implicit argument to survive that information to runtime.

```
final class AllNoneable[H <: HList] private (val allNone: H) extends AnyVal
object AllNoneable {
    implicit val allNoneableHNil = new AllNoneable[HNil](HNil)
    implicit def allNoneableCons[H >: None.type, T <: HList](implicit t: AllNoneable[T])
    = new AllNoneable[H :: T](None :: t.allNone)
}
```

Also, `hnilCase` does nothing.

```
trait LowPriEnsureOptional extends Poly1 {
  implicit def somethingCase[In]: Case.Aux[In, Option[In]] = at(Some(_))
}
object EnsureOptional extends LowPriEnsureOptional {
  implicit def optionCase[In <: Option[_]]: Case.Aux[In, In] = at(identity)
}
def optionalizeCase
  [C, Rep <: HList, Opt <: HList](c: Option[C])
  (implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, Rep], opt: Mapper.Aux[EnsureOptional.type, Rep, Opt],
    nones: AllNoneable[Opt]): Opt
= c match {
    case Some(c) => opt.apply(gen.to(c))
    case None => nones.allNone
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7DkpRePSSLu9hCX6KTDcOw)